# Connecting a ceiling fan with lamp to white and blue house wires

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

I've purchased a Hampton Bay ceiling fan with a lamp and I'm trying to connect it to my house wiring.
I can see the following house wires:

- 2 connected (twisted) white wires
- one wire of blue'ish color (maybe purple, I'm not good with colors)

What I've tried:

- I connected the white fan wire to the white twisted pair of house wires.
- All the other fan wires were connected to the blue house wire.
  Result: short circuit and a broken switch.

House wires:
[image]

Fan wires (2 green, blank, white, blue):
[image]

How should I connect my ceiling fan to the house wires that I have?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of *both* the fan and switch boxes please?

Comment: All the other fan wires ? Connected together?  If there is a green or green with a yellow strips that will create a short to ground. Don’t hook up wires just to hook them up some may not be needed or for other options. What are the colors of the other wires?

Comment: Sorry for not adding the photos, I've amended my question

Comment: We need to see pics of the insides of both the ceiling box and the switch box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These fans have one hot wire for powering the fan (usually the black) and another another hot wire powering the light (usu blue). These go to separate pull chain switches in the fan assembly.

The fan and light share a neutral (white). Note that in your house wiring all neutrals will be white, but depending on the age of your house, white may be used for a hot or switched hot so it is not correct to just connect all whites without knowing the function of a given white.

The green is a ground so if you connected the green to either the black or the blue it would short to ground as soon as the switch was turned on with the breaker on. The green should be connected only to the ground of the house wiring.

If you have only one wall switch and so only one hot wire from the house (black), then connect the black and the blue of the fan to the black of the house. Separate pull chain switches allow  separate control of fan and light.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Comment: So the fan's black and blue will connect to the house's blue'ish (non-white) and the fan's green (2 of them) and white will connect to the house's white. Right?

Comment: The fan's black and blue are to be connected together to the switched hot (a hot controlled by the switch). The switched hot may be either black or white depending on how the switch is connected. You need a voltage detector to be sure if a given white is a neutral or a hot (always hot or switched hot). The fan's white will be connected to the house neutral which will be white. The green of the fan will connect to the ground of the house wiring. This is usually a bare wire.

Comment: Thank you, Jim!
So in my case I do not have ground. I just see two connected white wires. I will double check them but they are not hot most likely. In this case (white is not hot), should I connect my fan's green wires (two) to the white wires?

Comment: This is in Chicago, right? And you have no ground? Is the wiring non-metallic (NM) cable, aka Romex? Or is the wiring individual wires in metallic conduit or flexible armored cable with no ground  wire inside? We need a picture of the ceiling box. You have already hung the fan so you may not be able to take an unobstructed pic. In that case you would need to get a voltage tester.

Comment: This is in Chicago. I have no ground. I have just checked my socket outlet. Only two wires, and no bare wire or anything like this. Also my white house wires (the twisted ones) are not hot

Comment: In case of old wiring with no ground there are different ways to proceed. If you would connect the fan green ground to the house neutral the fan would be powered but this would be a code violation due to shock hazzard if the neutral path would get interrupted in a certain way. The best way to treat this would be to get the circuit on a GFCI. Need experts to explain how to do this. I think if you can install a GFCI receptacle on this circuit between the fan and the panel, you could simply cap the green neutral of the fan. The fan would float ungrounded.

Comment: If your electrical boxes are metal and your wiring is in conduit or is armored flexible cable, you may have a ground path.

Comment: Thank you, Jim!
This is a metal box. One of the green wires goes from the ceiling part of the fan (where I actually hang the fan itself). I think they should have ground path. I plan to connect a green wire from the fan and that green wire and cap them

Comment: Jim, I've connected the fan and everything is working. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Yuri, glad to help. You should then "accept" my answer. I think you must click on a check mark or something like that.